# NullPointerException setOnClickListener

Tags: android, view, bluetooth, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I'm working on an app in Android Studio, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: please provide more information about your code and your view

Answer (score 0):

Check below things are done correctly:

1. Your button is present in the appropriate XML layout attached with the java code. Like this:

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/button_text" />
   ```
2. Check if this button is declared and initialized in your java code. Like this:

   ```
   Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
   ```
3. Check if an onClickListner is properly set to this button. Like this:

   ```
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Do something in response to button click here
           Toast.makeText(context, "button clicked!!!", duration).show();
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure, your button view is initialised (i.e. findViewById or through dependency injections) before setting up the listener on it.